# Cross join and aggregation in Vertica DB

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, vertica

I have two tables in Vertica Database

1) cross join of all existing locations and categories

```
location_1 category_1

location_1 category_2

...

location_2 category_1

location_2 category_2

...

location_n category_n-1

location_n category_n
```

2) list of items with locations and categories known:

```
item_1 location_1 category_4

item_2 location_8 category_3

...
```

I want to calculate, how many items is there in every location+category combination. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
   SELECT c.location, c.category, COUNT(i.item)
     FROM crosses c
LEFT JOIN items i
       ON i.location = c.location AND i.category = c.category
 GROUP BY c.location, c.category
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ad507/2).

The idea is the result of LEFT JOIN will have all the locations and categories from `crosses` table - but rows for missing items will be `NULL`-ed.

Answer (score 0):

i think this approach will work for you

```
    select Cross_j.location,Cross_j.category,count(item) from items
inner join
    (
    SELECT e.location,e.category FROM crosses as e CROSS JOIN crosses as w
    ) Cross_j
    on Cross_j.location=items.location and Cross_j.category=items.category
    group by Cross_j.location,Cross_j.category
```